# White space between tab and image of fragments

Tags: android, android-layout

I am working on GUi of my app and i have used the Actionbar sherlock and tabs and fragments.
There is white line (gap between tabs and image) i am trying to remove it but i cant. it only display on lower screen size size (less than 4 inch). It doesn't show on galaxy nexus .
[image]
Here is my Fragment XML file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/promo" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lv1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1" >
</ListView>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="100dip"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:layout_above="@+id/lv1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/mid_bar" />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:src="@drawable/play_button" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView2"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="14dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" 
    android:paddingLeft="10dip"/>
```

Comment: have you tried creating a layout file specifically for the smaller screens instead of just a generic xml file for all screens?

Comment: no not yet i am using generic xml..i created 3 folder layout-small, layout-normal and layout-large and according to that i change xml but still screen size having more than 3.7 inch takes xml from layout-large so what do i do now?

Comment: you could try layout-sw320dp this will target a typical phone screen size, also have you tried removing the margin from above your image view?

Comment: i have not used margin tab in my image view..

Comment: yeah sorry was looking at the wrong imageview haha you could maybe try a negative margin on the top of the image on the small screens xml

Comment: negative margin works for me to adjust the gap Thanks...

Comment: no problem glad i could help good luck with your app